# Cut a string in at a index and check if it in range 01-12. How to achieve it in shell?

Tags: shell-script

I have a string:

```
bDate = 20221201
```

I want to check if char at 5-6 are in range of 01 to 12
for this example it should match with 12.
for 20221309 if should say char at 5-6 is not in range of 01 to 12.
I am using cut in shell.

Comment: What is your string? Is it `bDate = 20221201` or is it `20221201`? And can you show us what you have so far so we don't waste your time with things you have already tried? Finally, what shell are you using?

Comment: Should the string `abcd12.zip` pass the test? The point of this comment is to ask whether you really just want to check those two characters, or whether you want to ensure that the string is a valid date on the YYYYMMDD format.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`:

```
printf '%s\n' 20221201 | awk '
    {match($0, /^[0-9]{4}([0-9]{2})[0-9]{2}/, a)
    if (a[1] > 0 && a[1] <= 12) {print a[1] " in range"}
    else{print a[1] " not in range"}}'
```

If the name of the variable is part of the string, simply remove the *anchor* `^`

With `BSD awk`:

```
printf '%s\n' 20221201 |
    awk '(length($0) != 8 || ! match($0, /^[0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{2}/))
    {print "wrong input"; exit}
    var = substr($0, 5, 2)
    if (var > 0 && var <= 12) {print var " in range"}
    else{print var " not in range"}}'
```

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
printf '%s\n' 20221201 |
    perl -nE 'my $m = $1 if /^\d{4}(\d{2})\d{2}/;
    if ($m > 0 && $m <= 12) { say "$m in range" } else {say "$m not in range"}'
```

With pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
bDate=20221201
[[ $bDate =~ ^[0-9]{4}([0-9]{2})[0-9]{2} ]] || { echo "wrong input"; exit; }
if ((${BASH_REMATCH[1]} > 0 && ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} <=12)); then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} in range"
else
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} not in range"
fi
```